# redefining one of the existing racket forms

Tags: racket

I'm designing a new language and would like to re-define the procedural form of `define` but export the standard expression form as well. Is there a way I can do that? So far I have this code:

```
(define-syntax-rule (my-define (name args) body ...) ...)

(provide (rename-out [my-define define]) define)
```

but generates the error "identifier already provided (as a different binding) in: define"

Comment: You can't export two bindings under the same name. You could export the old `define` under a different name though.

Comment: Though I suspect that's not really what you want. If I'm guessing correctly, you want a new `define` form that overrides some behavior, but falls back on the old behavior otherwise?

Comment: @AlexKnauth correct me if I'm wrong: I thought Racket has two forms of define: one that binds to an expr and one that binds to a procedure. 

I'd like to re-define one of them and export the other as is. I'm guessing from what you said that I basically can't do that and have to re-define a combined new form that check which form it is and then process accordingly?

Comment: True, there are two forms of `define`, but both are associated with the same identifier `define` so you have to handle both cases. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where `my-define` handles both cases.

```
#lang racket
(provide (rename-out [my-define define]))
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (my-define stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_define name:id e:expr)           (syntax/loc stx (define name e))]
    [(_define (name arg ...) body ...)  (syntax/loc stx (define (name arg ...) body ...))]))
```

Comment: The `e:id` means that `e` must be an identifier, and `e:expr` means that `e` must be an expression. The `id` and `expr` are syntax-classes, the common ones are documented here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Library_Syntax_Classes_and_Literal_Sets.html?q=syntax-parse